# Multi Container Deployment with docker on Azure using node.js - Backend and Frontend port mapping

Tags: azure, docker-compose

We are looking to deploy a node.js application which has the backend and front end in their own separate containers and have them talk to one another. We are using port 3000 for our front end and 8080 for the backend.

We are getting an error that says getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND the_server

At this time, we have removed the frontend application from the docker-compose.yml/config file and have tried to deploy only the backend. We are still receiving the same error.

Do we need a docker-compose.production.yml file for deploying on azure to expose the ports?

Answer (score 0):

For those that stumble upon this question; this functionality is currently in development for azure and is not supported as of 2/19/2021. It appears AWS does support this functionality though. I hope this points you in the right direction.